# Wire library and softwareSerial causing resets

Tags: arduino

We have this issue for 3 days now, where we have 3 arduino files :

```
main.ino  
module1.ino  //module 1 is using software serial on pins 5,6  
module2.ino //2 is using Wire library
```

Every module work by it self, but when we trying to work with them "together" from the main file we get endless resets  when :

**main:**

```
setup(); // 0 ( Wire connection setup)
clearAcInt(); //1  ( Wire connection)
connect(USER_SSID,USER_PASS); //2  ( software serial)
```

So using only 0+1 it works great,also using only 2 works, but using 2 after 0+1 would cause resets(setup function is committed )

**//0+ 1 wire connection module**

```
 #include <Wire.h>

   #define DEVICE (0x53) //ADXL345 device address
   #define TO_READ (6) 
   byte buff[TO_READ] ; 
   byte buffReg[8];  
   char str[512];    




void setup()
{
 Wire.begin(); 
}



 char *clearAcInt()
 {

         //**the cause of the problem:
         readFrom(DEVICE, 0x30, 8, buff); //0x30

         return "non";


 }
void readFrom(int device, byte address, int num, byte buff[]) 
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
  Wire.write(address);        //sends address to read from
  Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission

  //Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device (initiate again)
  Wire.requestFrom(device, num);    // request 6 bytes from device

  int i = 0;
  while(Wire.available())    //device may send less than requested (abnormal)
  { 
    buff[i] = Wire.read(); // receive a byte
    i++;
  }
 // Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission

}
```

**//2 SOFTWARE SERIAL**

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
   SoftwareSerial softSerial(5,6); 
   void setupCon()
{
 softSerial.begin(9600);
}
boolean connect(USER_SSID,USER_PASS)
{

    softSerial.println( ".sta.config(\""); 
   softSerial.println( ssid); 
    softSerial.println( "\""); 
    softSerial.println( ","); 
    softSerial.println( "\""); 
   softSerial.println(pass); 
    softSerial.println("\")");


}
```

**Removing 1 would fix the problem, also removing 2 would fix it .**
So it seems that the read function on the Wire module, would cause something that later you cant connect the software serial anymore .

We are really lost, so any direction would be great .
thanks .

Comment: Something is setting DTR and causing it to reset (like it should)

Comment: Thanks but what does it means and what should i do with this peace of information???

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear. DTR reset would only be applicable to if you open a com port from the PC. If that is not the case, you can ignore this :)

Comment: `#define TO_READ (6)` and `readFrom(DEVICE, 0x30, ` **8** `, buff);` don't match.

Comment: @Hanno To be honest i still dont know if i had to read 6 or 8 but this is actually DO work when there is no software serial..

Comment: @HannoBinder thank you thank you !!!! you solve our problem !!! it took us 3 full days till we found it !!!  you have no idea how much headache you save us by just writing this simple comment !!  thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help! - I don't know how exactly this interfered with the serial library, but writing beyond a buffer's allocated memory can potentially corrupt data used *anywhere* in the application, so that may have been the case.